# Camel route loops after a specific number of requests

Tags: java, apache-camel, endpoint

I'm having a problem with a Camel route I'm trying to solve for days now.

As I'm not a specialist for this technical issue, there might be omissions for the information you need to know...

First, the goal of my route is to connect to a distant server via an endpoint, requesting xml responses from xml requests via jaxb marshalling.

Nothing special in this route, which is the following one:

```
routeX.from("direct:requeteObjects)
.setHeader("element")
.constant(element)
.to("bean:importStructureI2VGestionnaireImpl?method=sendRequestObjects)                 
.to(endpoint)
.to("bean:importGestionnaireImpl?method=" + getObjects)
```

The server sends responses by pieces : for example, I'm expecting 3000 objects, received by packages of 30 objects.

My method that creates the request "sendRequest" is renewed and asks for the next objects.

After treating the response, I'm sending this request back to the endpoint, which gets the response, which is sent to the getObjects method, that processes the response.

Everything works well, I'm getting my responses. But after 5 requests/responses, after entering the endpoint, nothing happens. Debugging the code, it looks like there's a loop inside my route as the code keeps on going in the AsyncProcessor class, in the process method, etc. No logs, nothing. it doesn't stop.

I have no idea why it's going like that. I thought it might be because I was using the same route definition. So I created a route for each request, stopping and removing the old one. With this, I'm getting to 6 responses. But then, the same problem happens.

I tried setting the context maximum endpoint cache size and the context maximum cache pool size, multiplying by 10 the default values. I checked if the values were taken into account : they were. But still, I'm getting the same problem.

Also, the exchange object is always a new one, so my responses are never piled up inside one big exchange object.

Do you know where the problem could be? Can the context become too large? Or the endpoint? Where should I look?

Thank you for your answers. If you need any more information , I'll be pleased to add it.

PS : I tried applying the answer in this topic : [Camel route inside routeContext executing infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738832/camel-route-inside-routecontext-executing-infinitely), but no changes :-(